# calling structure not running prolog

Tags: prolog

i write this structure program on prolog like this

```
family(
person(tom,fox,date(7,may,1950), works(bbc,15200)),
person(ann,fox,date(9,may,1951),unemployed),
[person(pat,fox,date(5,may,1981),unemployed), 
person(jim,fox,date(5,may,1981),unemployed)]).
```

and when i put on prolog like this :

```
   ?- family( person( Name, Surname, _, works( _, _))),
       person(Name, Surname, unemployed)).
```

nad get an error : uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,family/2),top_level/0)

i try different ways to call it but still got no idea where is the error on this program. anyone got an idea about this ?

Comment: You forgot the third argument: the children. Nevertheless, I am not sure if this is a good way to represent a family, since the children `pat` and `james` can be married as well.

Comment: like this ?
husband(X):-
family(X,_,_).

wife(X):-
family(_,X,_).

child(X):-
family(_,_,Children),
member(X,Children).

member(X,[X|L]).

member(X,[Y|L]):-
member(X,L).

exists(Person):-
husband(Person);
wife(Person);
child(Person).

Comment: yes but it introduces a lot of data duplication, wich is considered an anti-pattern.